# How to make a cut out on objects created by modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I have an object (cube) replicated by modifiers. Now I want to cut out a dedicated other object (cylinder) from it using a boolean modifier (inspired by https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg?feature=shared&t=109). Here is my attempt which shows no effect regarding the cutout. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: just hide your cylinder and  if this doesn't work try clicking "fast", if this still doesn't work, pls provide blend file

Comment: .. just to illustrate  [Gordon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311914/35559)   : ..  https://imgur.com/a/HbyZrCH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason for the *Geometry to Instances* node? If not, just delete it:

[image: no instancing]

I do not know why inside the custom node group the *Duplicate Elements* node is set to *Instance* (EDIT: turns out, it only works with instances the way it is expected - I never use this node), but if it is necessary to convert the geometry, plug a *Realize Instances* node afterwards or at least as a final node before the output, because the *Boolean* modifier only works with "real" geometry, not instances:

[image: realize instances]

Comment: Beat me to it :) (Markus did show you the contents of the _Multiplikator_ group, in his illustration?)

Comment: @RobinBetts Sure, didn't look close enough and was already editing my answer ;)

Comment: Realize Instances solved it for me. The Geometry to Instances was something from one of the gazillion Blender "Experts" on YouTube (if only Blender had documentation that would be useful instead of this reference manual that helps nobody to approach it). As a nonnative English speaker I do not understand whether I need the G2I and RI thing or not. At least it did not work for me. Could you please clarify / show if and how?